# Calculating proportions by age in R

Tags: r, data-visualization

I working on this data set with marital status and age. I want to plot the percentage of never married man versus each age. Could you please help me to figure out the way how to do it in R? So far I have created two separate arrays with men never marries and ever married. I know how many case of each I have. What i need to do is to count number of people that were never married at each age and divide it by the total number of never married people to get a percentage. I hope I was clear. 
Thank you

Comment: Could you post a snippet of your data, so we have a better idea of what you want to manipulate?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your approach seems way too complicated to me. Let's start with some data:

```
## make up some data
status <- factor(rbinom(1000, 1, 0.3), labels = c("single", "married"))
age <- sample(20:50, 1000, replace = TRUE)
df <- data.frame(status, age)
head(df)
```

Print the first six cases:

```
> head(df)
   status age
1 married  21
2  single  50
3  single  43
4  single  28
5 married  28
6  single  40
```

Next, we need to calculate row wise percentages; even if I doubt that this makes sense (it refers to your statement: "What i need to do is to count number of people that were never married at each age and divide it by the total number of never married people to get a percentage.").

```
## calculate row wise percentages (is that what you are looking for?)
(tab <- prop.table(table(df), 1)*100)
```

The resulting table looks like this:

```
> (tab <- prop.table(table(df), 1)*100)
         age
status          20       21       22       23       24       25       26
  single  1.857143 3.142857 3.428571 2.285714 2.142857 2.857143 3.428571
  married 2.333333 2.333333 5.666667 1.333333 3.333333 5.333333 2.000000
         age
status          27       28       29       30       31       32       33
  single  2.857143 3.142857 3.428571 3.285714 2.714286 3.714286 3.571429
  married 5.000000 4.333333 2.666667 4.000000 1.666667 4.666667 3.000000
         age
status          34       35       36       37       38       39       40
  single  3.000000 2.857143 5.000000 3.571429 2.857143 3.571429 3.000000
  married 3.333333 4.000000 4.000000 2.333333 2.000000 2.000000 2.000000
         age
status          41       42       43       44       45       46       47
  single  4.285714 3.000000 3.714286 3.857143 2.857143 3.714286 1.714286
  married 2.333333 3.333333 2.000000 4.333333 3.666667 5.333333 2.666667
         age
status          48       49       50
  single  2.857143 3.428571 4.857143
  married 2.333333 3.000000 3.666667
```

That is, if you sum up row wise, it gives 100%

```
> sum(tab[1,])
[1] 100
```

Finally, plot it.

```
## plot it
plot(as.numeric(dimnames(tab)$age), tab[1,], 
     xlab = "Age", ylab = "Single [%]")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. That's exactly what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 5):

I did something similar recently.  There are quite a few ways to aggregate data like this in R, but the `ddply` function from the package `plyr` is my security blanket, and I turn to it for things like this.

I'm assuming that you have individual records for each person in your dataset, with age, sex, and marital status.  There's no need to split up the data into multiple tables for this approach - if you have women in the original table, just leave them in and add sex as a grouping variable.

```
require(plyr)
results.by.age <- ddply(.data = yourdata, .var = c("sex", "age"), .fun = function(x) {
    data.frame(n = nrow(x),
               ever.married.n = nrow(subset(x, marital.status %in%
                                            c("Married", "Divorced"))),
               ever.married.prop = nrow(subset(x, marital.status %in%
                                            c("Married", "Divorced"))) / nrow(x)
               )
    }
)
```

This splits the data.frame `yourdata` by unique combinations of the variables `sex` and `age`.  Then, for each of those chunks (referred to as `x`), it calculates the number of people who belong to that group (`n`), how many of them are married (`ever.married.n`), and what proportion of them are married (`ever.married.prop`).  It will then return a data.frame called `results.by.age` with rows like

```
sex       age    n       ever.married.n     ever.married.prop
"Male"    25     264     167                0.633
```

This is perhaps not the most elegant or efficient way to do this, but this general pattern has been very helpful for me.  One advantage of this is that you can easily and transparently collect whatever statistics you want from the subset, which can be helpful if you want to, say, add a regression line to the plot (weight by `n`) or have both male and female proportions on the same plot and color the points by sex.

---

Here's a revised version using the `summarise()` function from plyr - the effect is the same, but `summarise()` has a couple of key advantages:
 - It works within the environment of the current subset - so rather than typing `x$marital.status`, I can just type `marital.status`.
 - It lets me refer to other variables I've already created, which makes percentages, transformations and the like much easier - if I've already made `num` and `denom`, the proportion of `num` is just `num / denom`.

```
results.by.age <- ddply(.data = yourdata, .var = c("sex", "age"), .fun = summarise,
    n = length(marital.status),
    ever.married = sum(marital.status %in% c("Married", "Divorced")),
    ever.married.prop = ever.married / n # Referring to vars I just created
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably what you need is `table` or `aggregate`. If you add more details I can give you a more in-depth explanation.